# Passing an string parameter in JPQL native query

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have the following JpaRepository method:

```
  @Query(value = "select * from default_price_view where product_code  @> '{:productCode}'", nativeQuery = true)
  Page<DefaultPriceView> findDefaultPricesByProductCode(Pageable pageable,
      @Param("productCode") String productCode);
```

product_code is an array of strings with the format in Postgresql:

```
{021715,X91778,W21722}
```

Can you please tell me how I could add the parameter productCode into the query because currently it doesn't work :-(

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: Try: `@> cast(:productCode as text[])`

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name, unfortunately it doesn't  work. I found another solution that will avoid using arrays in sql.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you have product_code is an array in Java, and in Postgresql it's with this format {021715,X91778,W21722}

If this is the case, Try to define a string :

`String productCodeString = "{" + productCode[0] + "," + productCode[1]+ "," +productCode[2]+ "}";`
and use it in your request `:productCodeString`